# Remove unclosed XML tags

Tags: php, xml, curl

I need to fix unclosed/invalid/malformed xml tags while using CURL with CURLOPT_RANGE to get part of xml file

I'm trying to load only part of XML without downloading entire XML file and then parse it with [simplexml_load_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) function

You can see on this image i stopped downloading XML file using
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-2500');` and trying to parse string to valid XML but i can't understang how to achive this

searching on google is enought because i can't find real solution for my specific task so i'm asking here

**I need to remove unclosed  tags and format string to valid XML.**

[image]

Comment: why chunk it at all, you need the whole XML file to parse

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't need whole xml file because i load feeds from different xml files and need just two items from each one

Comment: curl knows nothing of the document nor where the items are in the byte range, as said you need the whole XML file to parse into XML, you could use regex to pull out the first 2 items and construct valid XML to parse, but is stackoverflow blasphemy to suggest that

Comment: You could try using [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php), this reads the XML as it goes along and so can read partial XML.

Comment: If you use a streaming event-based parser (I don't know what's available in PHP) you can simply abandon parsing as soon as you've seen the two items you are looking for; you don't actually need to repair the XML document.

Comment: You need to load the full xml and then extract the two items you need, or if you own the server where the xml is stored try making a function which you can pass with api like `limit=2` to only load 2 items

Comment: Thank you for your time but is there any way to "fix broken" XML?

Answer (score 0):

XMLReader can read partial XML, you can use it to expand the "item" elements into DOM and append them to an new document allowing you to merge the items of several partial XMLs into a new feed or directly get data from each item.

```
$sourceURLs = [
    'data:text/xml;base64,'.base64_encode(getXMLString())
];

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$collector = new DOMDocument();
$collection = $collector
  ->appendChild($collector->createElement('rss'))
  ->appendChild($collector->createElement('channel'));
$collector->documentElement->setAttribute('version', '2.0');


foreach ($sourceURLs as $sourceURL) {
    try {
        $reader = new XMLReader();
        $reader->open($sourceURL);
        
        // look for the first "item" element node
        while (
          $reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'item'
        ) {
          continue;
        }
        
        // iterate "item" sibling elements
        while ($reader->localName === 'item') {
          // expand into DOM
          if ($item = @$reader->expand($document)) {
              // append "item" to target document
              $collection->appendChild($collector->importNode($item, TRUE));
              
              // you can fetch data from the expanded node directly
              var_dump(
                [
                  // fetch node text content as string  
                  'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item)
                ] 
              );
          }
          
          // next "item" sibling
          $reader->next('item');
        }
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}

$collector->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $collector->saveXML();

function getXMLString() {
    return <<<'XML'
    <rss version="2.0">
      <channel>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <item>
          <title>Item 1</title>
        </item>
        <item>
          <title>Item 2</title>
        </item>
        <item>
          <title>Item 3</t
XML;
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(6) "Item 1"
}
array(1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(6) "Item 2"
}
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
          <title>Item 1</title>
        </item>
    <item>
          <title>Item 2</title>
        </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```